# Django Class based list view

Tags: python, django, listview

How to get a list of n no.of model entries  from a model having m no.of entries

Indetail.....I have a model of 50 entries i want a query set of 6 ramdom entries from that 50 entries using built-in class based ListViews.

I am portfolio_list give me all the entries of model present but i need only random 6 entries for index list display.

views.py

```
class PortfolioListView(ListView):
    model = Portfolio
    template_name = 'portfolio/portfolio_index.html'
```

portfolio_list.html

```
{% block Body_Content %}
  {% for item in portfolio_list %}
    <div class="card-group">
      {% include "portfolio/_portfolio.html"  %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock Body_Content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting it in the `queryset` attribute, for example:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class PortfolioListView(ListView):
    model = Portfolio
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.order_by('?')[:6]
    template_name = 'portfolio/portfolio_index.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override `get_queryset` method to build your custom queryset.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Portfolio.objects.order_by('?')[:6]
```

> Note: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on
> the database backend you’re using.

Comment: it work but as you said taking more time... anyway thanks